# Return one table from cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Please see the code below:

```
    DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @errorflag int

DECLARE Warning_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM Warnings
    SET @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error  
    OPEN Warning_cursor
        SET @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error  
        FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @ID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    begin
        SELECT @ID
        FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @ID
    END
CLOSE Warning_cursor
DEALLOCATE Warning_cursor
```

The cursor returns three tables with one row each.  How can I return one table with three rows?

Comment: @marc_s, it must be TSQL

Comment: @Jodrell, it is SQL Server 2005.  Thanks for tagging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do,

```
SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM Warnings
```

---

More generally, if you are using a cursor, you are probably doing it wrong.

---

If you really have to use a cursor for some reason that is not part of the question. You could do

```
DECLARE @Id int;
DECLARE @Ids TABLE (Id Int);
DECLARE Warning_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM Warnings;
OPEN Warning_cursor; 
FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @Id;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT @Ids SELECT @Id;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @Id;
END
CLOSE Warning_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Warning_cursor;
SELECT Id FROM @Ids;
```

Comment: There is a lot more logic contained in the cursor, which I have excluded because it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @w0051977, ok but, you are probably doing it wrong. It seems that logic is relevant in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a temporary table as follows:

```
   DECLARE @ID int
DECLARE @errorflag int
DECLARE @CONCATRESULT TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE Warning_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TOP 3 ID FROM Warnings
    SET @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error  
    OPEN Warning_cursor
        SET @errorflag = @errorflag + @@Error  
        FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @ID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    begin
        INSERT into @CONCATRESULT (ID) VALUES (@ID)
        FETCH NEXT FROM Warning_cursor INTO @ID
    END
CLOSE Warning_cursor
DEALLOCATE Warning_cursor
select id from @CONCATRESULT
```

Comment: A temporary table is not quite the same thing as a table variable but, for your purposes, a table variable is the best choice. It helps that your are using 2005+.